# Logging data that could not be processed for later review

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server stored procedure performing databases integration for the two independent systems. Simply speaking, it inserts data in the one database table based on the another database table records and some business logic. Some data can't be inserted because of missing attributes, or violating business rules, or something else. This procedure is scheduled to run in two hours.

After the procedure completion I need the list of unprocessed data to look through for the data issues. What is the best way of exporting the data from the stored procedure? I've looked at the two possibilities:

1. logging via RAISERROR
2. returning unprocessed data as the output of the stored procedure

Both of them look uncomfortable to use.

Could I use Reporting services somehow? Or is it better to create the separate table containing unprocessed records?

Comment: Are you inserting row by row?

Comment: I would use separate table

Comment: Well, I`ve planned to insert the whole bunch of records using subselect. But I`m studing business rules now and it may be necessary to process data row by row. What does it change in the scope of the question?

Comment: I would use separate table too, it's easy to use and research errors statistics. Also in this case you haven't to transmit incorrect data back to the server (which calls stored procedure), process it some way and log (especially if you'd like to log it in database). We use approach with separate table, and created report in reporting service for this, it's quite useful for monitoring process.

Answer (score 0):

If you insert data row by row as Raj asked you, so you can use `OUTPUT` clause in your `INSERT` statement. So you'll be able to log successful inserts easily - [MSDN link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).